# Arrange array from string csv

Tags: php, laravel

I need to transform my base64 CSV string, to a line where I take $line[0], $line[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NjW0.png) etc..

```
// my file uploaded
"filestream": "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"
```

I give back from: `$csvFile = str_getcsv($request->json('filestream'), '|');`

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NjW0.png)

the result expected is: Array( array(row), array(row2), array(row3) )

Comment: $result = explode('|', base64_decode($filestream));

Comment: I've already base64 decoded, but I need to slip array in each line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str_getcsv()` expects a single line, so you'll have to base64 decode the original string, then split that by newline to get multiple lines, then loop over those with `str_getcsv()` to get the array for each line. Something like this:

```
$array = [];
foreach (explode("\n", base64_decode($string)) as $line) {
    $array[] = str_getcsv($line, '|');
}
print_r($array);
```

You might add some extra checks to skip the blank lines in the input if those are not significant.